# Button in Table Cell not Triggering Event asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, onclick

Didn't find a concrete answer about this so here it goes... I'm creating an HTML table in a `foreach` loop where each time it creates the row for its corresponding order. I have two buttons as shown in the code below:

```
 private void CreateOrderTable(List<Order> orders)
    {
        OrderModel model = new OrderModel();

        foreach (Order order in orders)
        {
            Order orderN = new Order();



            //Create HTML Table
            Table table = new Table { CssClass = "cartTable" };
            TableRow a = new TableRow();
            TableRow b = new TableRow();

            //Crear cells for row a
            TableCell a1 = new TableCell { RowSpan = 2, Width = 50 };
            TableCell a2 = new TableCell
            {
                Text = string.Format(order.OrderID.ToString()),
                HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left,
                Width = 350
            };
            TableCell a3 = new TableCell { Text = "Monto:<hr/>" };
            TableCell a4 = new TableCell { Text = "Restaurante:<hr/>" };
            TableCell a5 = new TableCell { Text = "Estado<hr/>" };
            TableCell a6 = new TableCell { Text = "Tarjeta<hr/>" };
            TableCell a7 = new TableCell { Text = "<asp:LinkButton  OnClick=\"AcceptPayment\" runat=\"server\" class=\"myButtonGreen\">Aceptar Pago</asp:LinkButton>" };
            TableCell a8 = new TableCell { Text = "<asp:LinkButton  OnClick=\"RejectOrder\" runat=\"server\" class=\"myButtonRed\">Anular Orden</asp:LinkButton>" };

            //Create cells for row b
            TableCell b1 = new TableCell { };
            TableCell b2 = new TableCell { Text = order.Amount.ToString() };
            TableCell b3 = new TableCell { Text = order.Restaurante.ToString() };
            TableCell b4 = new TableCell { Text = order.OrderState.ToString() };
            TableCell b5 = new TableCell { Text = order.CardNumber + " " + order.CardDate };
            TableCell b6 = new TableCell { };


            //Add cells to columns
            a.Cells.Add(a1);
            a.Cells.Add(a2);
            a.Cells.Add(a3);
            a.Cells.Add(a4);
            a.Cells.Add(a5);
            a.Cells.Add(a6);
            a.Cells.Add(a7);
            a.Cells.Add(a8);




            b.Cells.Add(b1);
            b.Cells.Add(b2);
            b.Cells.Add(b3);
            b.Cells.Add(b4);
            b.Cells.Add(b5);
            b.Cells.Add(b6);

            //Add rows to table
            table.Rows.Add(a);
            table.Rows.Add(b);

            //Add table to panel
            pnlShoppingCart.Controls.Add(table);

        }
    }

    protected void AcceptPayment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void RejectOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

and the `OnClick` Event that I call is not being accessed, as I put debug markers on VS.

Why would this be?

Also, how would I pass an int to the event?

Comment: you tried to use <asp:LinkButton instead "<a>" ?

Comment: @Paulo yeah, doesn't change the situation. I have markers to debug and it doesn't enter the method which is calling

Comment: In this case you need post the complete code because so many things can be the problem.

Comment: @Paulo just edited to insert whole code

Comment: Why are you making a string of your `LinkButton`? You probably should be creating a `new LinkButton()`, attach the event then add it to the Controls of that TableCell.... like `a7.Controls.Add(new LinkButton...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating strings of your `LinkButton`'s you should probably be creating actual `LinkButton` (or `HtmlAnchor`) objects then add them to the Controls collection of your table cell.

Like this:

```
var lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = "Aceptar Pago";
lb.CssClass = "myButtonGreen";
lb.Click += AcceptPayment;

a7.Controls.Add(lb);
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thanks a lot.. Another thing, how would I send my orderID to those methods?

Comment: For this usually I use the `CommandArgument` field of the `LinkButton`. So when you create your LinkButton do something like this: `lb.CommandArgument = "123";`, then in your click event cast the `sender` as a `LinkButton` and get the order ID from the `CommandArgument` - maybe like this: `var lb = (LinkButton)sender; var orderId = Convert.ToInt32(lb.CommandArgument);`